# JPA 2.1 find by hint, returns redundant result if multi @NamedSubgraph exist in @NamedEntityGraph

Tags: hibernate, jpa, repeat, subgraph

I take advantage of **JPA 2.1** in conjunction with **Hibernate 5.0.2.final** in my project.

The issue is the fact that when I load an instance of type {@EventTO}, if this instance has no attendees and assignedResources or one of these collections at a time, it will load properly; however, if it has both of these collections, simultaneausly, the fetched result by entity graph will carry redundant data. For instance, if there are 3 attendees and 2 assignedResources, as a clue it will return 4 attendees and 3 assignedResources. I am bewildered by such a behaviour. I don't know why???. Probably it relates to the hibernate query, but I'm not sure.

Now, I would appreciate it if anyone could help me find genius solution for this problem.

The mentioned entities along with the code snippet which calls find method of JPA entity-manager, are as follows:

EventTO entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CALT_EVENT")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "seq_cal_event", allocationSize = 1)
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "loadGraph",
            attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "attendees", subgraph = "attendees"),
                    @NamedAttributeNode(value = "assignedResources", subgraph = "assignedResources")
            },

            subgraphs = {
                    @NamedSubgraph(name = "attendees", attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("departmentAttendee"), @NamedAttributeNode(value = "personAttendee")}),
                    @NamedSubgraph(name = "assignedResources", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("resourceTO"))
            }
    )
})
public class EventTO {
    private List<EventAttendeeTO> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendeeTO>();
    private List<EventAssignedResourceTO> assignedResources = new  ArrayList<EventAssignedResourceTO>();

    /**
     * @return the attendeesTOList
     */
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "eventTO", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     public List<EventAttendeeTO> getAttendees() {
         return attendees;
     }

     /**
      * @param attendees the attendeesTOList to set
      */
     public void setAttendees(List<EventAttendeeTO> attendees) {
        if (attendees != null) {
            this.attendees = attendees;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the assignedResourceTOList
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "eventTO", orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<EventAssignedResourceTO> getAssignedResources() {
        return assignedResources;
    }

    /**
     * @param assignedResources the assignedResourceTOList to set
     */
    public void setAssignedResources(List<EventAssignedResourceTO> assignedResources) {
        if (assignedResources != null) {
            this.assignedResources = assignedResources;
        }
    }
}
```

EventAttendeeTO entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CALT_EVENT_ATTENDEES")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "seq_cal_event_attendees", allocationSize = 1)
public class EventAttendeeTO extends RecordableExtEntityTO {
    private EventTO eventTO;
    private PersonTO personAttendee;
    private DepartmentTO departmentAttendee;

    /**
     * @return the eventTO
     */
    @JSON(serialize = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EAT_EVN_ID", nullable = false)
    public EventTO getEventTO() {
        return eventTO;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventTO
     *            the eventTO to set
     */
    public void setEventTO(EventTO eventTO) {
        this.eventTO = eventTO;
    }

    /**
     * @return the attendee
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EAT_PER_ID")
    public PersonTO getPersonAttendee() {
        return personAttendee;
    }

    /**
     * @param personAttendee
     *            the personAttendee to set
     */
    public void setPersonAttendee(PersonTO personAttendee) {
        this.personAttendee = personAttendee;
        if (personAttendee != null) {
            this.perId = personAttendee.getId();
        }
   }        

}
```

EventAssignedResourceTO entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CALT_EVENT_ASSIGNED_RESOURCE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "seq_cal_event_assigned_res", allocationSize = 1)
public class EventAssignedResourceTO extends ExtEntityTO {

    private EventTO eventTO;
    private EventResourceTO resourceTO;

   /**
    * @return the eventTO
    */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EAR_EVN_ID", nullable = false)
    public EventTO getEventTO() {
        return eventTO;
    }   

    /**
     * @param eventTO
     *            the eventTO to set
     */
    public void setEventTO(EventTO eventTO) {
        this.eventTO = eventTO;
    }

   /**
    * @return the resourceTO
    */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EAR_ERS_ID")
    public EventResourceTO getResourceTO() {
        return resourceTO;
    }

    /**
     * @param resourceTO
     *            the resourceTO to set
     */
    public void setResourceTO(EventResourceTO resourceTO) {
        this.resourceTO = resourceTO;
    }
}
```

Code snippet which call find method of entity manager by means of hint:

```
    try {
        EntityGraph graph = this.em.getEntityGraph("loadGraph");
        Map hints = new HashMap();
        hints.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
        return em.find(EventTO.class, id, hints);             
    } catch (Exception e) {
        new DAOException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After revising my code and thinking long and hard about this issue, the following reason come to my mind:

This problem could be related to hibernate limitation in loading multiple collections at the same time. As my ORM is hibernate, it could pose such an issue in fetching my TO.

 
**More details:** Hibernate throws following exception in fetching multiple bags with one query:

> org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously
>   fetch multiple bags

Maybe using NamedGraph causes hibernate to create a query based on wrong outer left joins which results in fetching redundant or in other words invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that hibernate creates query, then gets list of rows from database. and every row contains all the data: event + attendees + resources so it is not possible to keep track of how many entities go in which list. 
I don't know is it possible in all cases, but I use Sets to solve that problem. 
Keep in mind you need to implement equals (and hashCode) method when you are using sets.